# ORA-03111: Ruptura en el canal de comunicación visual studio

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Pasa que estoy realizando una conexión con código a una base de datos oracle sin embargo  me marca el siguiente error:

> ORA-03111: Ruptura en el canal de comunicación visual

He intentado con otras *Base de Datos* y si me ha funcionado correctamente mas sin embargo en la que deseo consultar datos no funciona.

Alguna solución a esto? ya he buscado pero no he encontrado nada.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podes descartar absolutamente que el problema no sea esa DB en particular? porque por lo que contas, ese parece ser el problema

Comment: Es correcto pero lo que deseo es lo grar la conexión a esa base de datos.